# How do I force the statusbar attribute of a Traits View object to update/redraw itself?

Tags: python, enthought, anaconda, canopy, traitsui

Ever since I switched from Canopy to Anaconda, the *statusbar* of my View is no longer updating itself dynamically, as my program runs. How can I force this to happen, at certain points within my program's execution?

I have this:

```
traits_view = View(

    {much code omitted.}

    statusbar = "status_str",
    title='PyBERT',
    width=1200, height=800
)
```

and *status_str* is updated several times during my program's run. Under Canopy, I used to see these changes occur in the GUI. Now, under Anaconda, I don't. So, I'd like to force them to occur. How do I do that?

Comment: Does the status bar demo (https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Advanced/Statusbar_demo.py) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to restore dynamic status updating to my application, by giving the simulation proper its own thread to run in. Many thanks to @Gael Varoquaux for his excellent tutorial on this topic, which you'll find here:

[Breaking the flow in multiple threads](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html#breaking-the-flow-in-multiple-threads)